# How to script to go to the deepest folder directory from parent directory to execute a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to automate converting .vmx to .ova by ovftool, and these .vmx files are generated from ghettoVCB. So I am writing a script to get converting automation working.

My question is how do I write a shell script that goes through each directory from a parent_directory and executes a command in each directory? Or could move everything from the deepest folder to parent_directory? (This solution may take time consuming to move those files from the deepest folder to parent_directory).

The directory structure is as follows:
parent_directory/automation/automation-2016-04-18_19-08-32/automation.vmx
parent_directory/bulls/bulls-2016-04-18_18-28-57/bulls.vmx

Here is another structure layout

parent_directory

- automation

  - automation-2016-04-18_19-08-32

    - automation.vmx
- bulls

  - bulls-2016-04-18_18-28-57

    - bulls.vmx

The name of subfolders from parent_directory does not follow patterns. Could be any name.
The folder "automation-2016-04-18_19-08-32" is the name of subfolder + date + time.

Comment: Do you want to move the files or do you just want to run some command on each `.vmx` file you find?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please select an answer to let everyone know. If it hasn't, please let the person who answered know why the solution is not working for you. It is just common courtesy.

Comment: @EtanReisner Either way, I am using the move files way that John1024 gave me. It's working fine.

Comment: Moving a file from one directory to another (so long as they are on the same filesystem) is just a simple renaming operation and actually extremely fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach 1

> move everything from the deepest folder to parent_directory

This command will search subdirectories of the current directory, find all `.vmx` files, and move them to the current directory:

```
find . -type f -name '*.vmx' -exec mv {} . \;
```

#### Approach 2

> write a shell script that goes through each directory from a parent_directory and executes a command in each directory

The following command will search for every subdirectory of the current directory and execute `command` in it:

```
find . -type d -execdir command \;
```

If you want to run `command` in every directory that contains `.vmx` files and supply the names of those `.vmx` files as arguments to `command`, then run:

```
find . -type f -name '*.vmx' -execdir command {} +
```

Alternatively, suppose we want to run the command once for each `.vmx` file that we find:

```
find . -type f -name '*.vmx' -execdir command {} \;
```

Comment: `-execdir` needs to be terminated with a `+` instead of `\'` (I know you know, I suspect a typo `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good suggestion.  I added an example showing the use of the `+` form for `-execdir`.  I kept the example of the `;` form (which also works).

Comment: Mybad - both is the best solution.

Comment: @John1024 here is a ovftool command: ovftool /directory/automation.vmx /directtory/automation.ova. So my question is when you use find . -type d -execdir command \; to execute command, then how to get the name of the file (automation or bulls or any name from different folder) for command?

Comment: For `ovftool` (and other commands that need single files as argument) using `-execdir +` is incorrect and using `-execdir \;` is correct.

Comment: @heaven I just updated the answer with a method for executing the command once for each file found with the file's name on the command line.